# Adding numbers using HTML forms and PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, math

I'm trying to make a simple web application that adds scores from a physical game such as Scrabble.  Most of the code is a HTML form, asking for one input per form element.  It then puts the data generated from the form and initializes the appropriate variables.  The one part I can't figure out is how to add the new score to the last score.  I tried to add variables, like $lastScore, but that didn't seem to work either.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<?php
//Gets data from HTML form
$addScore1 = $_REQUEST['addScore1'];
$addScore2 = $_REQUEST['addScore2'];

//Generates HTML form
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Score Add</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id=\"displayNames\">

    <p>
    $player1
        <form method=\"post\" action=\"\">
            <label for=\"addScore1\">Enter your score:</label>
            <input type=\"text\" name=\"addScore1\" id=\"addScore1\" />


            <input type=\"submit\" />
        </form>
    </p>

    <p>
    $player2
        <form method=\"post\" action=\"\">
            <label for=\"addScore2\">Enter your score:</label>
            <input type=\"text\" name=\"addScore2\" id=\"addScore2\" />

            <input type=\"submit\"/>
        </form>
    </p>
</div>
</body>

</html>";


?>
```

Comment: Please clear some ambiguities: ... Most of the code is a HTML form ***(I couldn't find where you used any PHP code in the html form)***, asking for one input per form element ***(What kind of input? integers I guess)***. It then puts the data generated from the form ***(to where)*** and initializes the appropriate variables ***(Match inputs to variables)***. The one part I can't figure out is how to add the new score to the last score. I tried to add variables, like $lastScore ***(Where is this from?)***, but that didn't seem to work either. ... any suggestions? Not Yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On submit, the script is calling itself and loses all the variables. You need to store their current score, e.g. in the session, in a database, or in a hidden field in the form.

With hidden field in your form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <label for="addScore1">Enter your score:</label>
    <input type="text" name="addScore1" id="addScore1" />
    <--! the addition is done in the next line in value-->
    <input type="hidden" name="oldScore1" id="oldScore1" value="<?=($oldscore1 + $addScore1)?>" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Do the same with your second form --> `oldScore2` etc...
At the top of your script, read the oldscore from `$_REQUEST`

```
//Gets data from HTML form
$addScore1 = $_REQUEST['addScore1'];
$addScore2 = $_REQUEST['addScore2'];
$oldScore1 = $_REQUEST['oldScore1'];
$oldScore2 = $_REQUEST['oldScore2'];

// as alternative, do the addition here:
$oldScore1 += $addScore1;
$oldScore2 += $addScore2;
```

Comment: Here's the full comment (sorry for the confusion): Thanks!  Your code works, but now I have another question: how do I then add them?  I tried at the bottom of the code; right after the closing HTML tag, such as:    echo $addScore1 + $oldScore1; but it doesn't add them.  It just displays the score I just entered.  Any other ideas? (I'm really kind of new to this :) )  Thanks,  Max 

Comment: @MaxIsom: edit the code in your question and show me where you display  the score, pls

Comment: There, it's added for you. <input type="hidden" name="oldScore1" id="oldScore1" value="<?=($oldscore1 + $addScore1)?>" />. Next Step: You do know how to use what's been added. Most recent score would be in the hidden field. Else do your adding where the variables are declared so you could use the sum in subsequent codes.

Comment: @michi  You can access the application at:  http://ripdvd.x10.mx/index.php  (Just ignore the 'ripdvd' part.  I'm not sure why I chose that name.:) )  NOTE: Only the top textbox works.  I haven't enabled the bottom one yet.

Comment: If it's not working, change <?=($oldscore1 + $addScore1)?> to <?php echo ($oldscore1 + $addScore1); ?>. I do have shortcode disabled on my server. That could be giving beginners some challenges... In case you need that.

Comment: @MaxIsom: There's something wrong with the code generating the HTML on your example. The sourcecode of the hidden field is: `<input type="hidden" name="oldScore1" id="oldScore1" value="<?php =( + 20)?>" />` see the `value`!

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting your code as a whole, try it:

I edited all those `<?php=$somevalue?>`because they don't seem to work with your PHP-setup, and replaced them with `<?php echo $somevalue> ?>`... let me know how it works...

```
<?php
// Get data from HTML form. $_POST is fine, because form method is set to POST.
$addScore1 = $_POST['addScore1'];
$addScore2 = $_POST['addScore2'];
$oldScore1 = $_POST['oldScore1'];
$oldScore2 = $_POST['oldScore2'];

// if these are numeric values, add them up
if (is_numeric($addScore1) && is_numeric($oldScore1)) $oldScore1 += $addScore1;
if (is_numeric($addScore2) && is_numeric($oldScore2)) $oldScore2 += $addScore2;

// Generate HTML form -- in HTML, much to complicated in PHP, unless it is necessary for sth else
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Score Add</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="displayNames">   
            <p><?php echo $player1; ?> current score: <?php echo $oldScore1; ?>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <label for="addScore1">Enter your score:</label>
                <input type="text" name="addScore1" id="addScore1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="oldScore1" id="oldScore1" value="<?php echo $oldscore1; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" />
            </p>

            <p><?php echo $player2; ?> current score: <?php echo $oldScore2; ?>
                <label for="addScore2">Enter your score:</label>
                <input type="text" name="addScore2" id="addScore2" />
                <input type="hidden" name="oldScore2" id="oldScore2" value="<?php echo $oldscore2; ?>" />
                <input type=\"submit\"/>
            </form>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like it should work, but it still doesn't!  I don't know why, everything looks right.  Here's the error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/ripdvdx1/public_html/scoregen.php on line 21    I re-hosted the file, so you can check it out yourself.  Again, thanks for helping me! - Max 

Comment: Please access my working setup at: ripdvd.x10.mx/index.php  Maybe from there you can debug.  I sure can't!

Comment: @MaxIsom: I can't see the php, only the HTML generated from it on your site. seems that PHP is not delivering the values to the HTML...  
pls insert <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> in your script after the <body>, and upload it to your server...

Comment: When I try to view it, an error gives way:  Warning: phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons

Comment: I found the .htaccess file.  Is there anything in here that I can add that will help debugging?

Comment: @MaxIsom sorry, not really. Seems that your php is pretty restricted... try posting a new question detailing what doesn't work to get help with the underlying problem. Good luck and keep on coding!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help!  -Max 